# SQL Server Merge column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not a DBA, but I'm trying my best to collect a bunch of data and merge it all into a single cell.

```
SELECT 
    ats.SupervisorSkillTargetID [AGENT],
    STUFF ((SELECT '' + ats.AgentTeamID as [text()]
            FROM Agent_Team_Supervisor ats
            FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '' )[TEAM]
FROM 
    Agent_Team_Supervisor ats
WHERE 
    ats.SupervisorSkillTargetID = '1234'
ORDER BY 
    AgentTeamID
```

The output I get is;

```
AGENT | TEAM
-------------
1234  | 000500050015001500150015001500150015001500150015001500250025002500350035003500350035003500350035003500350035004500450045004500450065007500750075007500750085009500950095009500950095009500950095009500950095011501150115011501150115011501250125012501250125012501250135013501350135013501350135013501450145014501450145014501450145016501650165016501650165016501650165016501650165016501650165016501750175017501750175017501750175017501750185018501850185018501850185019501950195019501950195019501950195019501950205020502050205020502050205020502150215021502150215021502150215021502150215021502150215021502150215021502150215022502250225022502250225022502250245025502550255025502550255025502550255027502850285029503050305030503050305030503050305032503350345035503850385038503850385038503850385038503850385038503950395039503950395039503950395039503950395039504050405040504050405040504050405040504050405040504150415041504150415041504150415041504150415041504250425042504250425042504250425042504250425042504350435043504350435043
```

28 times, which is the number of times 1234 is mentioned in the table, I'm trying to just output 1234, all the TEAMS that user is a part of.

I realise that Team is an INT and not TEXT, but I cannot seem to get it to work using CAST or anything else to merge it,

What I'd love to see is;

```
AGENT | TEAM
------+-------------------------
1234  | 5000, 5001, 5002, 5003
```

I'm not sure why the '000' is inserted first as that isn't, the 1234 Agent can only be in a possible once;

```
AgentTeamID
5000
5001
5002
5003
5004
5006
5007
5008
5009
5011
5012
5013
5014
5016
5017
5018
5019
5020
5021
5022
5024
5025
5027
5028
5029
5030
5032
5033
5034
5035
5038
5039
5040
5041
5042
5043
```

Comment: Yor sub query in Stuff() lost "where" clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @ats table (SupervisorSkillTargetID varchar(4) 
default('1234'),AgentTeamID varchar(4))

insert into @ats (AgentTeamID)
select '5000' union select '5001' union select '5002' union select '5003' 
union 
select '5004' union select '5006' union select '5007' union select '5008' 
union 
select '5009' union select '5011' union select '5012' union select '5013' 
union 
select '5014' union select '5016' union select '5017' union select '5018' 
union 
select '5019' union select '5020' union select '5021' union select '5022' 
union 
select '5024' union select '5025' union select '5027' union select '5028' 
union 
select '5029' union select '5030' union select '5032' union select '5033' 
union 
select '5034' union select '5035' union select '5038' union select '5039' 
union 
select '5040' union select '5041' union select '5042' union select '5043'

SELECT distinct ats.SupervisorSkillTargetID [AGENT], 
STUFF (( Select ',' + ats.AgentTeamID as [text()] FROM @ats ats where 
SupervisorSkillTargetID='1234' FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '' )[TEAM] 
FROM  @ats ats
WHERE ats.SupervisorSkillTargetID = '1234' 
ORDER BY [AGENT],team
```

the result is :

```
1234    5000,5001,5002,5003,5004,5006,5007,5008,5009,5011,5012,5013,5014,5016,5017,5018,5019,5020,5021,5022,5024,5025,5027,5028,5029,5030,5032,5033,5034,5035,5038,5039,5040,5041,5042,5043
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Wangguanguo I ran the query as; 

SELECT distinct ats.SupervisorSkillTargetID [AGENT], 
STUFF (( Select '' + ats.AgentTeamID as [text()] FROM Agent_Team_Supervisor 
ats where SupervisorSkillTargetID='1234' FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '' )[TEAM] 
FROM Agent_Team_Supervisor ats 
WHERE ats.SupervisorSkillTargetID = '1234' 
ORDER BY ats.SupervisorSkillTargetID

Because ', ' complained about it not being a valid integer, I'm still getting the leading 000;
000500150025003500450065007500850115012501350145016501750185019502050215022502450255027502850295030503250335034